# How to propagate ListViews in Layouts in ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

In my android app I have a ViewPager which has 2 Views inside, navigation_activity and another variable layout. When the app is started it starts on home_activity (which is the variable layout for the start) however if you slide left to he navigation bar and click on a button I need the variable layout to swap from home to another view... for now I have a system like this:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter
{
static int iFocusedActivity = R.layout.activity_home;

public int getCount()
{
    return 2;
}

public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) 
{            
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    int resId = 0;
    switch (position) 
    {
    case 0:
        resId = R.layout.activity_navigation;
        break;
    case 1:
        resId = iFocusedActivity;
        break;
    }
    View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
    return view;
}

public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1)
{
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
}

public static void setFocus(int iActivity)
{
    iFocusedActivity = iActivity;
}

public void destroyItem( View pager, int position, Object view )
{
    ((ViewPager)pager).removeView( (View)view );
}
```

}

It changed views fine, (where the setFocus() is called and a new adpater is given to the pager) the problem is I have a layout called layout_verblist with a ListView which needs to be propagated when the layout is adopted by the pager but simply calling code on the button click doesn't do anything...This proves to be a huge problem. How can I propagate the list of the layout in the Viewpager?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense(it also doesn't help that you're not consistent with the names of the layout files). Maybe you can explain better the desired behavior and the problem.

Comment: essentially the ViewPager holds 2 views, a navigation bar and one that is affected my the navigation bar. however if verblist is selected on the navigation bar it needs it's onCreate() method (for verblist) called in order to set up the list itself...

Comment: `onCreate` for what? A view/layout doesn't have a `onCreate` callback, like an `Activity` or `Fragment` for example(and if you are referring to the `onCreate` callback of the `Activity` then your app structure is incorrect from the start and you should revise it).

Comment: I did. Orignally all my views where Activities which were independant but when I swapped I kept their activity class, I guess what I should do this is remove the classes and manage the layouts from the MainActivity's onCreate()

Comment: You should really look into refactoring your code to use `Fragments`. Also the navigation in your app doesn't sound to good(If I fully understand it) you may be better off using tabs for switching layouts.

Comment: problem is tabs aren't supported by api 8 I don't think and a lot of my target are api8 which means they need would have a way to navigate? You don't happen to you about the keyboard thing do you?

Comment: Tabs can be implemented in some ways to that Api level, `ActionBarSherlock`, Fragments etc. I don't know about the `EditText` behavior maybe you're overlapping views so the `EditText` doesn't receives events. Just a guess.

Comment: I will have a think about those tabs, in either case they will come in handy for something else in the app later on. Also I fixed the keyboard, I had to clearFocus() on the Pager

Comment: Regarding the original question, how can I propagate the list in a layout when the layout becomes part of the pager?